# Command 'php' not recognized but it is registered in Windows PATH

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have "C:\Ampps\php" setup in the PATH string on my Windows server but when I type 'php' on the PHPStorm terminal I'm always given `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Is this a bug with PHPStorm 7.1.3? It works from the command line if I open a new Command Prompt window externally.

Comment: Try restarting PHPStorm if you added PHP to the PATH while it was open. If not, you should be able to specific `C:\Ampps\php` somewhere in PHPStorm's settings.

Comment: `Settings | PHP | Interpreters` -- that's where you define PHP executable that will be used by PhpStorm. unfortunately this will not help when executing `php` in built-in terminal since environment variables are inherited from DOS/System. Therefore -- try restarting IDE; if nothing -- restart whole PC.

Comment: @LazyOne That fixed the problem of the unresponsive PHP. However, now when I try to run 'php composer' I'm given the error `Could not open input file: composer`.

Comment: Do you have composer in your PATH? More importantly - do you have it in the folder where you trying to execute this command?

Comment: I have composer registered in PATH. Thought that would let it work anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

For any new readers facing such problem in PhpStrom just set path directly from PhpStrom terminal

```
set path=%path%;c:/xammps/PHP
```

Not recommended to use PHP from xammps or other such programs since it will be your working PHP directory and if it gets deleted then you have to perform another task to handle it or some errors might pop up in windows just install a fresh version of PHP lots of tutorials are out there for Windows.

But nevertheless to use PHP in PhpStrom Terminal from xammps just run that command it will set the path that PhpStrom can find.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have "C:\__OPENSERVER__\modules\php\PHP-7.2-x64" setup in the PATH.
To solve it I added in PhpStrom terminal and executed:

```
set path=%path%;C:\__OPENSERVER__\modules\php\PHP-7.2-x64
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open setting in file menu
2. find tools tab in this window
3. click on terminal
4. in project setting click on environment variable
5. add php path (for example "C:/xampp/php") to this and save
6. restart phpstorm

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, instead of linking to images