# 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable

Tags: php, phpstorm

I can start php serve on CMD

[image: see image]

but in PhpStorm I got this error:

> C:\Users\ferdi\www\blog>php artisan serve
>   'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I try to solve other way in "System Variables" but I cannot edit. Because no options edit or add.

[image: see image]

How can I start 'php serve' on PhpStorm ?

Comment: You'll need to install php.

Comment: install php ?..

Comment: This seems basic problem, ... Here are 3 similar questions:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt)

[link2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206344809--PHP-is-Not-Recognised-in-Command-Line-Why-)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974476/command-php-not-recognized-but-it-is-registered-in-windows-path)

Comment: yes, if you're writing php code, you'll probably want to install php.

Answer (score 1):

Add the php path to `file->setting->tools->terminal->Environment variables` and then restart your IDE:

[image: this picture help you to do]